# Time complexity of matrix subtraction

Tags: complexity-theory, matrix

If I have (I-Z) where I is a 3x3 identity matrix while Z is a 3x3 lower triangular matrix, how many subtractions that I should count from this process? 
Is it costs K subtractions or  (K^2+K)/2 subtractions?

Thank you.

Huda

Answer (score 1):

It’s a 3x3 matrix, so it can be done in constant time O(1). I can’t see where a “k” comes into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are subtracting $Z$ from $I$, you must compute the lower part of the matrix. If it was reversed, you only had to compute the new diagonal. The total number of subtractions is therefore $(k^2 + k)/2$.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by 'note the −k, as you are counting elements twice'.  Lets me show you how I got $ (K^2+K)/2 $.   I found that the number of subtractions is 1 in the first row, 2 subtractions in the second row, and 3 subtractions in the third row. Using mathematical induction, I got $ 1 + 2 + 3 = \sum_{i=1}^K i = \frac{K(K+1)}{2}$

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's indeed $+k$. In any case,  it's definitely not $k$ subtractions.